# Why socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) return -1?

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm writing a socket c++ lib for TCP.
I'm compiling with GCC for x86_64-w64-mingw32.7.3.0 on windows 10.

When I try to build a socket I fail.

```
listenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (listenSocket < 0) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: OPEN SOCKET" << listenSocket << std::endl;
    close(listenSocket);
    return;
  }
```

Getting the error.

> ERROR: OPEN SOCKET-1

Seem a really basic operation, I don't really understand why this failed.
Unfortunately, I don't have other information to debug it further.

Do you have some suggestions?
Thank you in adavance.

Comment: Here's a very obvious suggestion: look at what you get in `errno`.

Comment: If the `socket` call failed, you don't need to call `close` on the socket.

Comment: And as mentioned by @SamVarshavchik, check `errno` to see what's wrong. Use for example the `strerror` function to get a printable string: `std::cout << "Error creating socket: " << strerror(errno) << '\n';`

Comment: I've added this line std::cout << std::strerror(errno) << '\n'; before the close. This is the result message: No error.

Comment: Add it directly after the call that failed. Not after the cout.  And use WSAGetLastError. See [socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket) docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write any socket based code in **Windows**, you need to start your application with `WSAStartup()`. Add it to your program if you have not. In addition, you need to finish your application with `WSACleanup()`. **These 2 functions are windows-specific.**

Here is a small sample:

```
int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (err != 0)
        return 1;

    //...
    
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Here is [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup) page for `WSAStartuo()`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. This solves the problem! It is strange that win requires this.

Comment: @XaBerr it is a common problem for non-windows users trying posix sockets in windows. Just mark it as answer if solved your problem please. :D

Comment: I'm trying but I need to wait the minimum time to check.